# regex to remove first part of pathName

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I got a string which is actually part of an url, like this:

```
/m/some/url/string
```

I need to remove 1st part of this string, e.g. `/m/` to look it like this:

```
some/url/string
```

I tried this code:

```
var pathName = '/m/some/url/string'; 
pathName = pathName.replace(/^\/.[^\/]+\//g, ''); 
console.log(pathName);//same string here as it was
```

and verified in regex101.com that it worked. But when I launched this code in console, the string remained unchanged. Any ideas how to fix it? Thank you

**EDIT_1** Strangely enough, but it is working with `/my/` but not working with `/m/`. Any ideas why?

Comment: It is working in my chrome console.

Comment: are you sure is this the case? because i just copy paste your code in console and its working fine.

Comment: Why a regex? What abount finding the second '/' character and removing everything up to that point?

Comment: Yes, I have checked, it works with `/my/`, but not working with `/m/` (only 1 letter). Any ideas why? Updated the question

Comment: `'/m/some/url/string'.replace(/^\/.+?\//, '')`

Comment: To help you understand what's going on in your version, created a fiddle - https://regex101.com/r/DgL7cJ/1/
The trick is `.` matches any character and then you match `[^\/]+` which means "not / at least one to many times".  So these combined gives result of at least 2 characters between /.
Remove the `.` and you're good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Strangely enough, but it is working with /my/ but not working with /m/. Any ideas why?

Nothing strange here, your `\/.[^\/]+` regex is working with `/my/` and isn't working with `/m/` because it expects **at least two characters** after the first `/` because `.` matches exactly one character and `[^\/]+` matches at least one character, and `m` is 1 character that's why it wasn't matched.

So you need to remove the firts `.` in your regex :

```
/^\/[^\/]+\//g
```

Or you can just use `.replace(/^\/[\w\d]+\//, '')` like this:

```
str = str.replace(/^\/[\w\d]+\//, '');
```

**Demo:**

```js
var str = "/m/some/url/string";
str = str.replace(/^\/[\w\d]+\//, '');
console.log(str);
```

Comment: You can save 2 bytes by removing the parentheses... oh wait, this isn't [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-golf).

Comment: hhh @NH. well pointed out thank you, I was thinking in a `.match` way.